# Question about a not semisimple group algebra

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups

Let $K$ be a field, $G$ a finite group and $K[G]$ a group algebra.
We have the following result:

Theorem: if the characteristic of $K$ divides the order of $G$, then $K[G]$ is not semisimple.

Let $I:=\{\sum_{g \in G} a_g.g: a_g \in K, \: \text{such that} \: \sum a_g=0 \}$ a two-sided ideal of $K[G]$.
The idea is to prove that for each ideal $I$ of $K[G]$, there is no left ideal $J$ of $K[G]$ such that $K[G]=I \oplus J$ (i.e. such that $I \cap J=\emptyset$ and $I+J=K[G]$).

Please can someone give an explanation of the following sentence.

If $K[G]=I \oplus J$ for some left-ideal $J$ of $K[G]$, then $\dim J=1$ so it is spanned by, say, $\alpha=\sum_g b_g.g$.

I have difficulties to understand the notion of dimension of the ideal $J$.

Comment: $K[G]$ is a vector space over $K$ (as well as a ring), and the notion of dimension here is just the ordinary vector space dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $K[G]$ is a $K$-algebra, it follows that any ideal is in fact also a $K$-subspace (check this). So we can talk about the dimension of ideals in a $K$-algebra (as the dimension of the ideal as $K$-vector space).
Define

$$\omega: K[G] \to K: \sum_{g}k_g g \mapsto \sum_g k_g$$

Check that this is a $K$-algebra epimorphism. Note that $I= \ker \omega$ and from the isomorphism theorem we know that we have an isomorphism of $K$-algebra's

$$K \cong K[G]/I$$

Taking $K$-dimensions of both sides:

$$1=\dim_K (K) = \dim _K(K[G]) - \dim_K(I) = |G| - \dim_K(I)$$

and thus

$$\dim_K(I) = |G| -1$$

Since  $K[G]= I \oplus J$, we also have $$|G| = \dim_K(K[G]) = \dim_K(I) + \dim_K(J) = |G| -1 + \dim_K(J)$$

and we deduced that $\dim_K(J) = 1$. Thus $J$ is $K$-spanned by one element.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal $I$ you have defined is commonly called the *augmentation ideal* of the group ring, and it is the kernel of a ring homomorphism onto $K$.

Since the dimension of $K[G]$ is the finite cardinality of $G$, the rank theorem says that the dimension of $I$ as a $K$ vector space is $n-1$, and therefore its complement would have to be $1$ dimensional.

---

By the way, I find it much easier to show $K[G]$ is not semisimple by proving there is a nonzero central nilpotent element. This is necessarily in the Jacobson radical, and semisimple rings cannot have a nontrivial Jacobson radical.  One such central nilpotent element is $x=\sum_{g\in G}g$, which satisfies $x^2=|G|x$, and if the characteristic of $K$ divides $|G|$, the right side is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for those great answers. I didn't noticed that indeed $I$ was the kernel of the augmentation map (which is a ring homomorphism) $\omega(\sum_g k_g.g)=\sum_g  f_g \in K$ !

Comment: I'm trying to understand the last proof of rschwieb using Jacobson radical.

Comment: A central nilpotent element of any ring is in the Jacobson radical. The proposed element is central and squares to zero.  Need help with one of those or is there a different question you have?

Comment: If you have a $K$-algebra $A$ and you consider the principal ideal $aA=\{ax | \: x \in A \}$. Then you can define the nilpotency of this ideal by defining the set $(aA)^m$ whose elements are sums of elements of the form $ax_1ax_2...ax_m$ where $x_1,x_2,...,x_m \in A$. Then $(aA)^m=0$ if and only if every product of such a form is equal to zero, i.e. the product equals zero whenever $a$ appears $m$ times in the product. Those elements are called strongly nilpotents and every nilpotent element of the center of $A$ is strongly nilpotent. If $A$ is semi simple, it contains no nonzero st. nil. el.

Comment: rschwieb: Is my interpretation right ?

Comment: @beginarray I suppose that's one way to see it.  Another way to see it is that for any simple module $S$, $s\mapsto as$ is an $A$ linear homomorphism. If $a$ does not annihilate $S$, then it is an isomorphism of $S$. But then all of its powers are isomorphisms, which is a contradiction since $0$ is one of its powers.  Therefore it annihilates all simple modules.

Comment: Another way is to note that $ax$ is nilpotent for any $x\in A$, and then $1-ax$ is a unit for any $x\in A$, which is a way to conclude $a\in J(A)$.

Comment: Thank you rschwieb... I saw recently this criterion of semi simplicity in terms of representation theory: An algebra $A$ is semi simple if and only if there is a faithful semi simple $A$-module i.e. if Ann M=0.

Comment: @beginarray That's certainly true for finite dimensional algebras. Otherwise it's only equivalent to the Jacobson radical being trivial. You need both to get a semisimple Artinian ring.